# Laravel search among relations

Tags: laravel

I have a bit of code failing to achieve what I'm looking for. Auth User if owner of a company who owns clients, and clients buy product.

Basically I want to create a search amongs clients of the desired company (well user owned company) and potentially on products bought :

I tried this :

```
$clients_paginate = Auth::user()->company->clients();
if($q != ""){
    $clients_paginate->where("user_prenom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
       ->orWhere("user_nom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%'
       ->orWhere("societe_nom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
}
```

The problem I have is that it retrieves clients responding to query but which are not owned by the given company ! I thought the query would be restrained by the first relationship ->clients() but not the case !!!

Is there a way to cope the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it !!! Posting the solution in case it might help others

The relationship constraint is in in fact a simple where so query built was where client and where user_prenom or or.

The client constraint was just playing on first where clause and not two others. Simply grouping the three last worked

```
$clients_paginate->where(function ($query) use($q){
    $query->where("user_prenom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->orWhere("user_nom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->orWhere("societe_nom", 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
});
```

Comment: Also try using `whereHas` instead of where for closures to filter relationships and bring results with only matching records